# tableview inside a scrollview, tableview didselect is not working as expected

Tags: tableview, scrollview, height, didselectrowatindexpath, contentsize

I have a Scrollview -> ContentView -> UIVIew -> TableView
I am setting the scrollview contentsize,

self.ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: self.UIVIewHeight.constant)

now i can able to see all my tableview cells and it is scrolling till the tableview content, everything is fine. But the when i try to select the tableview cell, it is not working.
Just the cell at the top of the screen alone is working where as the other cells are not working.

I even added button to every tableview cell and tried with button action, the thing the frame of the tableview is short i think so, the cell at the top of the screen works where as the didselect on the other tableview doesn't work.

I referred many links and couldnot find any solutions, suggest me how to move in this

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html**Refer this link using tableview inside scrollview**

Comment: thanks for your quick response but my question is that am using a tableview inside a scrollview, there were nearly 4rows returned and all the four rows were shown and scrollable too till the end of tableview content but the only thing tableview didselect is not working for those cells, even i tried adding button with action and tapgestures.....nothing helps me. What are possible case, touch not working. Any help will be appreciated.